# How to convert MTM (canada) coordinates to latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, coordinates

I have a geojson file indicating some points of interest in Montreal but the coordinates arent't in lat and lng, instead they are X, Y coordinates in MTM nad83, zone 8.

And i'd like to load the file in google maps but the coordinates need to be converted..

I searched in internet a lot but all what i've found is a site capable of converting it : twcc.fr. And in the js source code, i didn't found anything so it is probably server-side.

Anyone who knows coordinates conversions ?

Thank's in advance

**EDIT : ** sample from the json file :

```
{"name":"json_sortie","type":"FeatureCollection"
,"features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[294079.844,5044618.5]},"properties":{"POTEAU_ID_POT":122476,"DATE_CONCEPTION_POT":20101216000000,"DESCRIPTION_REP":"Enlevé","DESCRIPTION_RTP":"2- Tige et manchon","X":294079.844,"Y":5044618.5,"ID_ARRONDISSEMENT":"25","TRC_ID":1110499}}
,{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[296910.375,5045914.5]},"properties":{"POTEAU_ID_POT":5766,"DATE_CONCEPTION_POT":20090707000000,"DESCRIPTION_REP":"Réel","DESCRIPTION_RTP":"3- Fût","X":296910.375,"Y":5045914.5,"ID_ARRONDISSEMENT":"25","TRC_ID":1090130}}
,{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[296908.938,5045915.5]},"properties":{"POTEAU_ID_POT":66342,"DATE_CONCEPTION_POT":20090707000000,"DESCRIPTION_REP":"Enlevé","DESCRIPTION_RTP":"1- Tige et base","X":296908.938,"Y":5045915.5,"ID_ARRONDISSEMENT":"25","TRC_ID":1090130}}
,{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[296481.188,5045804]},"properties":{"POTEAU_ID_POT":5030,"DATE_CONCEPTION_POT":20121108000000,"DESCRIPTION_REP":"Réel","DESCRIPTION_RTP":"1- Tige et base","X":296481.188,"Y":5045804,"ID_ARRONDISSEMENT":"25","TRC_ID":1100117}}
```

Comment: MTM is [Modified Transverse Mercator coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system).  The [wiki for UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Locating_a_position_using_UTM_coordinates) contains some equations that might be useful.

Comment: Plz check out here: http://canadiangis.com/converting-between-utm-mtm-and-latlong.php

Comment: I tried implementing the utm formulaes in javascript but i didn't work very well. Are you sure utm and mtm are so near ?

Comment: Check your UTM implementation by using an online UTM converter. The you have a strong hint, whether your UTM code is correct or not

Comment: I figured out that the error in my code was using radians rather than degrees. It have worked now and i've found how to make work MTM too (check my answser if you're interested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it. If you know how to convert UTM to WGS84 latitude, longitude, you can convert MTM. Equations to convert UTM to WGS84 (lat,long) are [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Locating_a_position_using_UTM_coordinates).

MTM is like UTM, but more precise. The zones are 3° large instead of 6° for UTM. The scaleTM is 0.9999 instead of 0.9996. The false easting is 304.8 km (instead of 500km for UTM).

To have the reference meridian in UTM you do `refMeridian = Zone * 6° - 183°`, but for MTM I used an array of zones corresponding to their reference meridians (that I've found on the internet):

```
var zone_to_refmeridian =  // MTM zone to reference meridian
  [0, 53, 56, 58.5, 61.5, 64.5, 67.5, 70.5, 73.5,
   76.5, 79.5, 82.5, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99,
   102, 105, 108, 111, 114, 117, 120, 123, 126,
   129, 132, 135, 138, 141];

// For instance for Montreal city which is in zone 8:
zone_to_refmeridian[8] // for zone 8
```

Answer (score 0):

This website was very useful to me in converting MTM to WGS84
http://leware.net/geo/utmgoogleapp.htm